# Обработчик события

Tags: html, javascript

Всем привет, есть такой вопрос по JavaScript.

У меня на странице есть переменные: ${1}, ${2}, ${3}. Есть форма с текстовыми полями и кнопкой. В текстовые поля вводим значения для этих переменных, далее при нажатии кнопки эти переменные будут принимать значения из текстовых полей и выводить их на странице.

С чего начать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начать лучше с прочтение книжки. Ну а если по задаче то так, даем текстовым полям уникальные id, типа

```
<input type="text" id="text_1" />
```

и т.д. Дальше вешаем на кнопку сабмита onClick функцию, которая с помощью getElementById будет забирать данные из инпутов, а потом в подготовленный заранее блок при помощи свойства  innerHTML будет выводить контент на страницу.

Еще инфо:

[Информация о getElementById](http://getelementbyid.ru)

[Свойство innerHTML](http://innerhtml.ru)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
<script>
function myf() {
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text').value;
}
</script>
Результат: <span id="result"></span>
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="submit" onclick="myf();">
```

Comment: Благодарю.